# How to change Facebook Application Platform status

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-authentication

I made an android app that connect to the facebook up
the problem is that when a user click the Login Facebook button
If His Facebook Application Platform is off, the program cant login and doesnt notify the user why.

How can I notify the user about this.
and if there is a why the change this On/Off setting through android app?

Answer (score 0):

you can see my post. I am using Facebook 3.0.1 SDK there . If facebook application is open, user isn't required to enter his/her password and username again , just a permission is wanted in this case in order to share someting. If facebook application isn't open,it directs the user to the login page . You can refer to my post ([Share via facebook/twitter application in android , don't open browser if facebook/twitter is installed on the device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17164455/share-via-facebook-twitter-application-in-android-dont-open-browser-if-facebo)) and see how it's done by checking the accepted answer . I hope it helps

Comment: Hey , by saying :"Facebook Application Platform is off"
I dont mean if facebook app is installed in the device.
this option is in the facebook user setting and if it set to off
the user cant add/authorize a app that connect to facebook