# Share via facebook/twitter application in android , don't open browser if facebook/twitter is installed on the device

Tags: android, facebook, twitter, share

As the title implies , I would like to share something via facebook/twitter in android .If the facebook/twitter is installed , I want to share the post via the fb/twitter application , otherwise I want to direct to the user to the browser . I can direct the user to the browser it is easy , but how can I share post via the fb/twitter application ?

Thanks..

(Editted)
I've tried to do this , examined developers.facebook.com , however they're doing this operation via fragments. I want to do it with default activity . I've tried the code below however I'm getting error like

```
W/dalvikvm(16093): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature     (Landroid/support/v4/app/Fragment;)
W/dalvikvm(16093): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/support/v4/app/Fragment;)
W/dalvikvm(16093): VFY: unable to resolve static method 367: Landroid/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager;.getInstance (Landroid/content/Context;)Landroid/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager;
```

The code I used in the default activity is :

```
private void publishStory() {
        Session currentSession = Session.getActiveSession();


        if (currentSession != null){


            Bundle postParams = new Bundle();
            postParams.putString("name", Commons.campaignname);
            postParams.putString("display", "touch");
            postParams.putString("link",  Commons.campaignlink");
            postParams.putString("picture",Commons.campaignimage);

            Request.Callback callback= new Request.Callback() {
                public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                    JSONObject graphResponse = response
                                               .getGraphObject()
                                               .getInnerJSONObject();
                    String postId = null;
                    try {
                        postId = graphResponse.getString("id");
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.i("TAG",
                            "JSON error "+ e.getMessage());
                    }
                    FacebookRequestError error = response.getError();
                    if (error != null) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                             error.getErrorMessage(),
                             Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                                 postId,
                                 Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            };

            Request request = new Request(currentSession, "me/feed", postParams, 
                                  HttpMethod.POST, callback);

            RequestAsyncTask task = new RequestAsyncTask(request);
            task.execute();
        }

    }

    private boolean isSubsetOf(Collection<String> subset, Collection<String> superset) {
        for (String string : subset) {
            if (!superset.contains(string)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;

}
```

Comment: you need to implement oAuthenitactation in your facebook id to open it. basically this problem start with new version start with 4.0

Comment: "I can direct the user to the browser it is easy"how do you direct user to the browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To post something using Facebook than integrate Facebook android sdk

[Getting Started with the Facebook SDK for Android](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/)

Use Feed Dialog to post on Facebook. It automatically open fb app if it is installed otherwise open in browser

[Post to wall](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/publish-to-feed/)

```
public class PhotoViewer extends Activity implements StatusCallback{

    Button btnShare;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_photo_viewer);

        btnShare = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnShare);

        btnShare.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Session.openActiveSession(PhotoViewer.this, true, PhotoViewer.this);

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {

        if (session.isOpened()) {
            publishFeedDialog();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    private void publishFeedDialog() {

    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("name", "Facebook SDK for Android");
    params.putString("caption", "Build great social apps and get more installs.");
    params.putString("description", "The Facebook SDK for Android makes it easier and faster to develop Facebook integrated Android apps.");
    params.putString("link", "https://developers.facebook.com/android");
    params.putString("picture", "https://raw.github.com/fbsamples/ios-3.x-howtos/master/Images/iossdk_logo.png");


        WebDialog feedDialog = (
                new WebDialog.FeedDialogBuilder(PhotoViewer.this,
                        Session.getActiveSession(),
                        params))
                        .setOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(Bundle values,FacebookException error) {

                                if (error == null) {
                                    // When the story is posted, echo the success
                                    // and the post Id.
                                    final String postId = values.getString("post_id");
                                    if (postId != null) {
                                        //Toast.makeText(PhotoViewer.this,"Posted story, id: "+postId,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Publish Successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    } else {
                                        // User clicked the Cancel button
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Publish cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                } else if (error instanceof FacebookOperationCanceledException) {
                                    // User clicked the "x" button
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Publish cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                } else {
                                    // Generic, ex: network error
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error posting story",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            }

                        })
                        .build();
        feedDialog.show();
    }

}
```

If you are not using a Fragment than use you **Context like ClassName.this** instead of **getActivity()**

**EDIT**

please add this code in onCreate() to print Hash key

```
// Add code to print out the key hash
PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.your.package", // replace with your package name 
PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
        md.update(signature.toByteArray());

        Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));

    }
```

Comment: Hi , I have examined the codes in the developers.facebook.com site. They're using fragments. However , I'm not using fragments , I couldn't achieve sharing posts on wall through the application. Could u guys help ? I've edited my statements above.

Comment: I used your advices but now I'm getting sessions cant be null error . I tried to open sessions in the code , but I failed. What do I need to do ? Thanks for your answer

Comment: Hi Kirit , thanks for your answer , I can connect the page it asks for permissions and after giving permissions, it doesn't show the webpage , it says web page doesnt exit , the page fbconnect://success#access_token=viceversa&expires_in=518370 . How can I solve this ?

Comment: Have you a create app on developers.facebook.com?

Comment: I cant show you the screenshot because my phone cant take screenshot of itself.And yes , I've already created my app on developers.facebook.com , I have also created my hash key too. What it says on the page is that : Web page not available. The webpage at fbconnect://success#access_token=something&expires_in=something might have been temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.My internet connection isn't broken.

Comment: Hey , I have updated the facebook and its working now =) I can share the post , however when I login out my facebook and login as a different user , still the previous user seems to share the last things (which are the things second user has shared actually)

Comment: Hi Krit , even if the user logs out , I can still share on facebook without athentication . How can I fix this ?

Comment: In general this will not happen but if it happen in your case than you can logout from android facebook app and than try to share on facebook

Comment: I have to fix this because it's an important problem . After user logs out from facebook , I shouldn't share on facebook without authentication. Do you have an idea ?

Comment: from facebook I am logging out , then I open my android application I can still share something via facebook , it doesnt want authentication

Comment: facebook means facebook android app or web?

Comment: have you add Facebook login activity in Menifest.xml  or not? like `<activity
            android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"
        </activity>`

Comment: also add meta for login activity `<meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />`

Comment: Can I do the same thing for twitter ? I would like to send tweets without opening browser if twitter is installed . Is this possible , do you know ?

Comment: Sorry. I never integrate twitter in app and I don't known about error why it happen in your case but i can suggest to once check all the step given at developers.facebook.com and also check your hash key

Answer (score 0):

by this code you can check if facebook or twitter application is installed on the device.
rest you can put your logic if condition is false

```
final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
List<ApplicationInfo> packages = pm
            .getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Installed package : " + packageInfo.packageName);
}
```

Then you can check if `packageInfo.packageName` is equal to some string which contains the package name of that application.